# get Select option text with VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a classic `<Select>` input, and I want to get the text of the selected element. I am able to get the value, but not the text:

```
<select v-model="ageCategory" class="form-control" @change="calculateCategoryName">
    <option value="0">{{trans('core.no_age')}}</option>
    <option value="1">{{trans('core.children')}}</option>
    <option value="2">{{trans('core.teenagers')}}</option>
    <option value="3">{{trans('core.adults')}}</option>
    <option value="4">{{trans('core.masters')}}</option>
    <option value="5">{{trans('core.custom')}}</option>
</select>
```

I can get value with :

```
var ageCategory = this.ageCategory;
```

But I can't get text... Any idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client-side rendered select options**

Since your values happen to be zero-based numbers (0 through 5), you could keep the translation keys in an array in the component:

JS:

```
data: {
    ageCategory: 0,
    ageValues: [
        'core.no_age',
        'core.children',
        'core.teenagers',
        'core.adults',
        'core.masters',
        'core.custom'
    ],
},
methods: {
    calculateCategoryName: function(event) {
        var ageCategory = this.ageCategory;
        var ageCategoryName = this.ageValues[this.ageCategory];
    }
}
```

Then you can render out those values using a [`v-for` loop](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html):

```
<select v-model="ageCategory" class="form-control" @change="calculateCategoryName">
    <option v-for="ageValue in ageValues" :value="$index">{{ trans(ageValue) }}</option>
</select>
```

**Server-side rendered select options**

If you need to get the value out of the actual select option, you can just get it through the DOM, [using `v-el`](https://vuejs.org/api/#v-el):

```
methods: {
    calculateCategoryName: function() {
        var ageCategory = this.ageCategory;
        var $ageCategorySelect = this.$els.ageCategory;
        var ageCategoryOption = $ageCategorySelect.options[$ageCategorySelect.selectedIndex];
        var ageCategoryName = ageCategoryOption.text;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select v-model="ageCategory" class="form-control" @change="calculateCategoryName" v-el:age-category>
    <option value="0">{{trans('core.no_age')}}</option>
    <option value="1">{{trans('core.children')}}</option>
    <option value="2">{{trans('core.teenagers')}}</option>
    <option value="3">{{trans('core.adults')}}</option>
    <option value="4">{{trans('core.masters')}}</option>
    <option value="5">{{trans('core.custom')}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is it a way to define ageValues in HTML? Thing is {{ trans('core.no_age'}} is a blade laravel directive who doesn't work out of a .blade.php file :(

Comment: I see. Have a look at the edit above. Does this help?

Comment: yes a lot! Can you explain the variable $index and $els. You are binding the option value to $index but I don't know what it means

Comment: You can ignore the `$index` part if you render it via the server (it is only relevant for `v-for` loops). `$els` allows you to reference DOM elements in your components that you define with the directive `v-el:...`. See: https://vuejs.org/api/#v-el

Comment: here is the bad point, in Laravel {{ }} is used to echo, so we use @{{ }} instead of {{ }} in vue. But then, I must get Vue var with @{{ ageValue }} (it works) and then apply {{ trans(... ) }} but it doesn't seems to mix well both @{{ }} and {{ }}

Comment: As far as I can see, you wont need to mix both of them in this case (only look at the `Server-side rendered select options` section :) ).

Comment: I get an error on both: $ageCategorySelect and ageCategoryOption : [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "function categoryFullName() {

Comment: uyy sorry I think I didn't modify HTML back. Now think it is better

Comment: Tx ! I got it working! They say Vue is so easy, but I think it is very difficult !!!

Comment: It takes a moment to get used to, just like any framework. Just keep going :) Best of luck.